# Como identificar um 'delimitador' em uma string com php?

Tags: php

No meu problema um delimitador são duas strings que 'englobam' uma parte de outra string em uma dada ordem.
Por exemplo: `'('`e`'}'` são um delimitador da string: `'aqui (tem} um delimitador'`.

Meu problema é como identificar um delimitador em uma string para substitui-lo por outro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que esta função pode te ajudar.
Caso tenha dúvida da sintaxe e outras opções consulte
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php

```
// Fornece: aqui tem} um delimitador
$bodytag = str_replace( "(", "", "aqui (tem} um delimitador");
```

Neste simples exemplo eu mudei apenas o caractere '(' por '' ,fiz isto para retirar o delimitador.

Caso queira substituir por algo coloque no parâmetro 2.
Você pode repetir a função para tirar quantos precisar ou fazer um array com os caracteres indesejados.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'ola {cabra} aaa';
$rules = str_replace(array("{","}"), array('[',']'), $string);
print($rules);
//retorna: ola [cabra] aaa
```

Comment: O exemplo perguntado não era ( com } ???

Comment: postei aqui apenas um rascunho da solução do meu problema.